# What's the python script to change the background color but not changing the object color at all and then rendering it?

Tags: python, rendering

So far I have

```py
 world = bpy.data.worlds['World']
 world.use_nodes = True
 bg = world.node_tree.nodes['Background']
 r = 1
 g = 1
 b = 1
 bg.inputs[0].default_value[:3] = (r, g, b)
 bg.inputs[1].default_value = 1.0
```

but this also affects the object color. Is there anyway I can just change the background color and save the scene with the changed background color?
Edit: I found a way using the method @BatFinger linked to and was able to code it in python with blender 2.8

```py
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True
#set up nodes to change background color
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
composite = tree.nodes[0]
render_layers = tree.nodes[1]
alpha_over = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeAlphaOver')
links = tree.links
link_1 = links.new(render_layers.outputs[0], alpha_over.inputs[2])
link_2 = links.new(alpha_over.outputs[0], composite.inputs[0])
alpha_over.inputs[1].default_value = (r, g, b, 1)
```

Comment: Maybe your object changes color because your background is coloring it?

Comment: @unwave How can I make it not do that?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108867/how-to-make-colored-backgrounds-not-influence-the-color-of-an-object